# Can I mount a React component automatically (like angularjs' direct)?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

### Update 3

I have been using AngularJs for several years, and want to try ReactJs. With AngularJs I can define a directive and put the node inside the HTML DOM, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
....
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--helloWorld is a directive-->
    <hello-world></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, in React, to my knowledge, one needs to call

```
React.render(
  <HelloWorld />,
  targetElement);
```

to mount the `component`. Is there a way in React to mount the component automatically?

I have created a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/MrCoder/pen/xboryG) to show my idea as an experiment. The main piece of code is as below:

```
function R() {
  var className = 'Hello';
  if (window[className]) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(className);
    angular.forEach(elements, function (element) {
      React.render(React.createElement(window[className]), element);
    });
  }
  setTimeout(R, 50);
}
```

Every 50ms, we will check if the Class has been created. If it is I will render it under the element in the real DOM node `<Hello> </Hello>`.

*Warning: this code works only in trivial cases.

The JSX code to create react class:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
  var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return <h1>Hello</h1>;
    }
  });
  // React.render could be called here, like below:
  React.render(
    <Hello> </Hello>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
  // but I want the <Hello> </Hello> stays in the html DOM. So that I don't
  // repeat calling React.render. The first piece of code, will find the
  // node and render the ReactClass there.
</script>
```

In html:

```
<Hello> </Hello>
```

I don't want to use `setTimeout`, but don't know if there are other approaches.

Comment: React has methods like componentDidMount where you could call you function. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: @Eagllus. I am looking for when Class is created, not component is mounted. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you looking to trigger an event when React.render is called ?

Comment: what do you mean by "the class has been created" ? more code would help

Comment: `React.createElement` call is synchronous.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard not when `React.render` is called, but when `React.createClass` is called, because otherwise, I will need to wait for the Class is ready to render it.

Comment: What's the point to create the class dynamically ? what is the code that creates the calss dynamically ?

Comment: Please checkout the [codepen](http://codepen.io/MrCoder/pen/xboryG) I added in the original quesiton.

Comment: Still don't understand why don't you wait for your classes to be declared then render it dynamically instead of making the declaration dynamically.

Comment: @XiaoPeng it looks like your problem is caused by using the in browser jsx transform, rather than compiling your code ahead of time.  If that's *not* the issue, then you have a code structure problem.  There are numerous systems for resolving dependencies in the correct order (including angular's modules).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do but you could use EventEmitter
to bind a listener when you class is created.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter; 
var assign = require('object-assign');

var myclassfactory= assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    addListener: function(myclassName,callback) {
        this.on(myclass,callback);
    },

    createClass: function(myclassName) {
      //create your class ===>>>>>> React.CreateClass !!
      this.emit(myclassName);
    }

});
```

Then add a listener in your view:

```
 myclassfactory.addListener(myclassName, render(myclassName));
 var render = function(myclassName) {
        React.render(myclassName, myelement);
 }
```

Comment: I meant listent to [React.createClass](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createclass);

Comment: I know, sorry I can't figure out what your are trying to do.

Comment: To put it simple, in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/MrCoder/pen/xboryG), I want to eliminate the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: Ask yourself why do you need it ... Put your script in a external file and load it at the end of your html document.